# GreenDao persistance issue

Tags: android, greendao

I am using greenDao in my app to persist complex object.

For example

```
class A{
id;
name;
List<B> list;
}

class B{
id;
name;
List<C> list;
}

class c{
id;
name;
}
```

I got the tables with all class fields(for all classes).

**Problem:**
I can see records for table A(for class A), tables B and C are empty(no records).

I am persisting object of class A like:

```
A toSave = //class generated by GSON

aDao = daoService.getADao();
aDao.insert(toSave);
```

Can you please  help me to solve this issue?

Also I cannot find in the documentation if is allowed to query dao object and retrieve object of class A with all information/fields automatically?

thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

GreenDao is not able to persist cascade data - If you say insertOrReplace(tvShow) it will not persist list of episodes and list of moments. In order to perform that you have to persist all data separately.

For example:

```
TvShowDao.save(tvShows) OR TvShowDao.insertOrUpdate(tvShows);
```

AND

```
EpisodesDao.save(episodes) OR EpisodesDao.save(episodes)
```

AND

```
MomentDao.save(moments); OR MomentDao.save(moments);
```

Important:

```
Note that save...() will do
```

- an insert for entities that have no ID and
- will do an update for entities that have an ID set.

[GreenDao Git Issue](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/521)

In other words, you have to persist all data separately.